# How to check the channel type of a message when using a discord bot

Tags: discord.io

while making a discord bot just for fun, I've been trying to make a tracking feature that reposts a message in a certain channel whenever a message is posted. receives in a certain channel. However, im trying to make it so it says what channel type it's in (Private DMs, server channel etc.) but i cant find any way to check the channel type. I've seen on the discord developer portal that there is a variable called 'type' which gives a number depending on the type, however u cant figure out any way to use it and there are no other people saying how to do this.
[basically im trying to figure out how to define channel type with discord io]

```
if (channelType == 0) {
      bot.sendMessage({
        to: '636271494980173834',
        message: '> ' + user + ' sent "' + message.substring(0) + '" in private DMs'
      });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the documentation
[doc](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/master/class/DMChannel?scrollTo=type)

so this:

```js
if (message.channel.type === "dm") {
      bot.sendMessage({
        to: '636271494980173834',
        message: '> ' + user + ' sent "' + message.substring(0) + '" in private DMs'
      });
    }
```

Comment: That didn't work, it said `Cannot read property 'type' of undefined` so I guess it can't find it for some reason

Comment: Try updating to the latest version because it looks like bot.sendMessage is from a older version

Comment: Ok this might be the problem => discord.io is last published 2 years ago which is old. Try using discord.js or discord.lib.